# No view found for id fragment

Tags: android

When I press the button in the InputFragmentNew fragment, I want the newRegistrationFragment to open. But when I try to open it, I have the following problem. How do I switch from one fragment to another?

**First Class**

```
  public class GirisFragmentNew extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

 btnKAyit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new yeniKayıtFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
}
```

**Second Fragment**

```
public class yeniKayıtFragment extends  Fragment {
    private yeniKayıtModel yeniKayıtModel;
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        yeniKayıtModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(yeniKayıtModel.class);

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yenikayit, container, false);
        Window window=getActivity().getWindow();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            window.setNavigationBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));}
  return root;
    }
```

**Second Class Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="...yeniKayıtFragment">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webviewYeniKayıt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `MainActivity` create this public variable
`public static FragmentManager manager;`

then inside the `onCreate`  method 
`manager = getSupportFragmentManager();`

then in your `GirisFragmentNew` fragment

```
btnKAyit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    yeniKayıtFragment fragment = new yeniKayıtFragment();
                    MainActivity.manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment,yenTAG).commit();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm having the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `Fragment` you have to use `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`. Don't use static variable which you have tried. Check below:

```
btnKAyit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new yeniKayıtFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
});
```